# Parsing and validating optional function arguments

Tags: javascript, function, validation, types, arguments

I'm looking for a simple way to manage function arguments. Here's what I'm looking for.

- Assign type or potential types
- Assign default value
- Pass in validate function or (array of functions), thrown if false (or one of functions is false)

I came across [ArgueJs](https://github.com/zvictor/ArgueJS) which has a ton of great features, however it does not do the following.

- [Allow for an argument to be potentially one of two types.](https://github.com/zvictor/ArgueJS/issues/19)
- [Allow for you to capture all passed in after the rest of the preceding defined arguments as an array.](https://github.com/zvictor/ArgueJS/issues/18)

That specific library hasn't been maintained or update for 2 years. So it's a little out of date.

I was just wondering if there's any mainstream way of managing arguments in general there's always way to much overhead. Ideally lets you validate using a validator function like the ones in [chriso/validator.js](https://github.com/chriso/validator.js).

Comment: Seems like something better suited to a tool like TypeScript. The overhead of doing this as runtime processing is going to be pretty severe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came across this

https://github.com/okunishinishi/node-argx

Here's an example

```
var express = require("express")
var argx = require('argx')
var _ = require("underscore")

function example(/*Router, method, url, middleware*/) {
  var args = argx(arguments)
  var Router = args.shift('function') || express.Router
  var method = args.shift('string') || "get"
  var url = args.shift('string') || "/"
  var middleware = _.flatten([args.remain()])

  console.log(Router)
  console.log(method)
  console.log(url)
  console.log(middleware)
}
```

Validation can happen at different layer on top of this.